# Dql select from many to many relation. How get all results (all tags from product)?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have problem with creating dql to get result from many to many relation.

I have two entity:

> product (id, name, tags) - code from product:

```
/**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(
    *       targetEntity = "Tag",
    *       inversedBy = "products"
    * )
    * @ORM\JoinTable(
    *       name = "products_tags"
    * )
    */
    private $tags;`

)
```

> tag (id, title) code from tag:

```
/**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(
    *       targetEntity = "Product",
    *       mappedBy = "tags"
    * )
    */
    private $products;
)
```

DQL code:
`$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT p.id as productId, t.title as productTag FROM My\AppBundle\Entity\Product p JOIN p.tags t WHERE p.id = 1');
$product = $query->getResult();`

When I want to use this dql, in my result i see only one tag

`array: [▼
  "productId" => 2
  "productTag " => "tag1"
]`
but this product has 3 tags. What i must to do when I want have all tags from this product?

Comment: Try to change **p** to **h**